# return multiple values from method using out string in c#

Tags: c#, string, methods, parameters, out

The `LoadEmployee` is a method too and I'am facing an error says:**`The out parameters 'Firstname' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method`** is there other way to return value without using `out parameter`

```
  protected void SplitName(string Name, out string FirstName, out string MiddleName)
    {

        char[] delimiterChars = { ',' };
        string[] name = acEmployee.Text.Split(delimiterChars);
        string Lastname = name[0];
        string middlename = name[1].Substring(Math.Max(0, name[1].Length - 1));
        string Firstname = name[1] = name[1].Remove(name[1].Length - 1);

    }


  private void LoadEmployee()

    {

        string name = acEmployee.Text;
        string firstname, middlename;
        SplitName(name,out firstname,out middlename);
    }
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, why do you have an assignment to `name[1]` in that last line? That makes the code significantly harder to read, IMO. (Additionally, I would strongly encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have them as local variables as you need to assign a value to the parameters you are passing in

```
protected void SplitName(string Name, out string FirstName, out string MiddleName)
{

    char[] delimiterChars = { ',' };
    string[] name = acEmployee.Text.Split(delimiterChars);
    string Lastname = name[0];
    Middlename = name[1].Substring(Math.Max(0, name[1].Length - 1));
    Firstname = name[1] = name[1].Remove(name[1].Length - 1);

}
```

What you could also do is have an object that wraps all of the names

```
public class Name
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string MiddleName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

and then you can return that from you method

```
protected Name SplitName(string Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign values to the `out` parameters, so replace the below

```
  string middlename = name[1].Substring(Math.Max(0, name[1].Length - 1));
  string Firstname = name[1] = name[1].Remove(name[1].Length - 1);
```

with

```
  MiddleName= name[1].Substring(Math.Max(0, name[1].Length - 1));
  FirstName= name[1] = name[1].Remove(name[1].Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete string tags because you have already declared them  in (protected void SplitName(string Name, out string FirstName, out string MiddleName))

`name = acEmployee.Text.Split(delimiterChars);
 Lastname = name[0];
 middlename = name[1].Substring(Math.Max(0, name[1].Length - 1));
 Firstname = name[1] = name[1].Remove(name[1].Length - 1);`